# How parsing XML(RowsetSchema) for using JAXB unmarshalling in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, sharepoint, jaxb, unmarshalling

i have XML from SharePoint(getListItems) without shema(used JAXB without @XmlRootElement).
I must create objects from this XML and use unmarshall(JAXB). All exampels that i saw - have shema. Can you help me or give example?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<GetListItemsResult xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
    <listitems xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
        <rs:data ItemCount="5">
            <z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_Created="2013-07-17 12:20:14" ows_Created_x0020_Date="1;#2013-07-17 12:20:14" ows_FSObjType="1;#0" ows_FileLeafRef="1;#1_.000" ows_FileRef="1;#Lists/000/1_.000" ows_ID="1" ows_LinkTitle="H1 2013" ows_MetaInfo="1;#" ows_Modified="2013-07-17 12:20:14" ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" ows_Title="H1 2013" ows_UniqueId="1;#{DD5DFA68-42E1-47BC-BBE3-9921D6093EB2}" ows__Level="1" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows_owshiddenversion="1"/>
            <z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_Created="2013-07-17 12:20:20" ows_Created_x0020_Date="2;#2013-07-17 12:20:20" ows_FSObjType="2;#0" ows_FileLeafRef="2;#2_.000" ows_FileRef="2;#Lists/000/2_.000" ows_ID="2" ows_LinkTitle="H1 2014" ows_MetaInfo="2;#" ows_Modified="2013-07-17 12:20:20" ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" ows_Title="H1 2014" ows_UniqueId="2;#{48F0F5E2-3DC6-4C7C-901A-5F33834DA619}" ows__Level="1" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows_owshiddenversion="1"/>
            <z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_Created="2013-07-17 12:20:25" ows_Created_x0020_Date="3;#2013-07-17 12:20:25" ows_FSObjType="3;#0" ows_FileLeafRef="3;#3_.000" ows_FileRef="3;#Lists/000/3_.000" ows_ID="3" ows_LinkTitle="H1 2015" ows_MetaInfo="3;#" ows_Modified="2013-07-17 12:20:25" ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" ows_Title="H1 2015" ows_UniqueId="3;#{40136C41-B7DA-42E4-B733-1B569C0AFEEB}" ows__Level="1" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows_owshiddenversion="1"/>
            <z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_Created="2013-07-18 17:05:48" ows_Created_x0020_Date="7;#2013-07-18 17:05:48" ows_FSObjType="7;#0" ows_FileLeafRef="7;#7_.000" ows_FileRef="7;#Lists/000/7_.000" ows_ID="7" ows_LinkTitle="Michael Drummond" ows_MetaInfo="7;#" ows_Modified="2013-07-18 17:05:48" ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" ows_Title="Michael Drummond" ows_UniqueId="7;#{057BB0DD-DA6F-45A4-8B85-809E09E79149}" ows__Level="1" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows_owshiddenversion="1"/>
            <z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_Created="2013-07-18 17:22:35" ows_Created_x0020_Date="8;#2013-07-18 17:22:35" ows_FSObjType="8;#0" ows_FileLeafRef="8;#8_.000" ows_FileRef="8;#Lists/000/8_.000" ows_ID="8" ows_LinkTitle="Michael Drummond" ows_MetaInfo="8;#" ows_Modified="2013-07-18 17:22:35" ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" ows_Title="Michael Drummond" ows_UniqueId="8;#{8E6F9D85-E360-41E8-87F8-65D071FE39AC}" ows__Level="1" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows_owshiddenversion="1"/>
</rs:data>
</listitems>
</GetListItemsResult>
```

Comment: Why don't you use xml schema? Sharepoint publishes WSDL out-of-the box. Just use http://[your-server]/your-site/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL extract the schema and and use in JAXB. Alternatively, you can run wsdl2java on this- it will create java (JAXB) bindings for you.

Comment: I did that. I exctracted my WSDL via maven. than `ListsSoap port = sharePointListsAuth(userName, password); GetListItemsResponse.GetListItemsResult result = port.getListItems("000", "", null, null, "", null, "");
            JAXBXMLHandler.marshal(result, new File("GetListItemsResult.xml"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you example there are a couple things you need to factor in namespaces and collections.

**Namespaces**

You can use the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation to setup the default namespace qualification.  Then since there are multiple namespaces involved you can use the `namespace` parameter on the `@XmlType`, `@XmlElement`, and `@XmlElementWrapper` to override the default where required.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

**Collections**

By default a JAXB implementation won't add a grouping element for collection properties this can be done with the `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html

Comment: Thank you. But i can't change Namespaces in my wsdl. And my mentor said do objects for controlling data in list from received file(XML).

Comment: @user1560783 - I didn't mean change the namespaces in your WSDL.  I just meant that there are multiple namespaces in your XML and you will need to account for this in your JAXB metadata.